# BUG: CME RT Editor causes the browser to become unresponsive

Tags: cme, schema, component

When using an embedded schema (multi) with 4 RTFs rendering the component in the CME with 80+ instances of the embedded schema field the browser becomes unresponsive and the tab/window needs to be closed down.

Comment: Is the 80+ instances (x 4 RTFs) of embedded fields a standard setup for your editors and do you have several of these Components in your implementation? I'm curious about the content model and use case. Also, please consider reporting the bug to Support. I'd prefer a fix, documentation on the issue, or perhaps an actual limit/warning if the UI has a limit like that.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the RTFs to standard text fields and the issue goes away.